# Itemized list is shown correctly but errors are shown in Logs

Tags: errors, itemize

I have this code:

where:

```
\begin{itemize}\quad
\item \textbf{E} is the electric field (V/m) \newline
\item \textbf{H} is the magnetic field (A/m) \newline
\item \textbf{D} is the electric flux density (C/m\textsuperscript{2})\newline
\item \textbf{B} is the magnetic flux density (Wb/m\textsuperscript{2})\newline
\item \textbf{M} is the (fictitious) magnetic current density (V/m\textsuperscript{2})\newline
\item \textbf{J} is the electric current density (A/m\textsuperscript{2})\newline
\item \(\rho\) is the electric charge density (C/m\textsuperscript{3})\newline
\end{itemize}
```

Output is as I want: a list of my symbol descriptions. But the Logs shows 26 errors. Error says: "There are no entries found in a list you have created. Make sure you label list entries using the \item command, and that you have not used a list inside a table." If I remove the trainling \newline all lines are printed as a paragraph of running text.
I HAVE USED \itemize as can be seen.
What can be wrong here. This is in Overleaf file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a compilable code, starting with `\documentclass`  ans ending with `\end{document}` , and loading all the relevant packages?

Comment: without a test file it is impossible to guess,(the error you show is not a standard latex error message) however the `\newline` commands are all in error and I would expect them to generate warnings.

Comment: The `\quad` following `\begin{itemize}` should also be removed since it will throw an error message. Removing that and the before mentioned wrong `\newline` commands, adding the `article` documentclass as well as `\begin{docment}` and `\end{document}`, the code compiles just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code which compiles without errors: I remavethe `quad` at the beginning of the itemize environment, and replaced each  `\newline` between items with the single key `item=` defined by the `enumitem` package. Further,  I used `siunitx` for the units, to have a better spacing between units symbols.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\DeclareSIUnit\C{C}
\DeclareSIUnit\Wb{Wb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[itemsep=\baselineskip]
\item \textbf{E} is the electric field (\si{\V/\m})
\item \textbf{H} is the magnetic field (\si{\A/\m})
\item \textbf{D} is the electric flux density (\si{\C/\m^2})
\item \textbf{B} is the magnetic flux density (\si{\Wb/m^2})
\item \textbf{M} is the (fictitious) magnetic current density (\si{\V/\m^2})
\item \textbf{J} is the electric current density (\si{\A/\m^2})
\item \(\boldsymbol{\rho}\) is the electric charge density (\si{\C/ \m^3})
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The wording of the error smells Overleaf, which tries to be more helpful than standard LaTeX, but here fails to.

The problem is simply the `\quad` after `\begin{itemize}`, which is completely out of place. If I remove it, I just get warnings about `Underfull \hbox`, which are caused by `\newline` (this is a ***very rarely*** used command).

Removing also the offending commands, I get a clean run.

[image]

However, it's better to use a dedicated package for the units.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{E} is the electric field (\si{\volt\per\meter})
\item \textbf{H} is the magnetic field (\si{\ampere\per\meter})
\item \textbf{D} is the electric flux density (\si{\coulomb\per\meter\squared})
\item \textbf{B} is the magnetic flux density (\si{\weber\per\meter\squared})
\item \textbf{M} is the (fictitious) magnetic current density (\si{\volt\per\meter\squared})
\item \textbf{J} is the electric current density (\si{\ampere\per\meter\squared})
\item \(\rho\) is the electric charge density (\si{\coulomb\per\meter\cubed})
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I wanted to avoid those bullet points. I simply wanted listing the variable descriptions at an indent from left page edge. How do I achieve that?

Comment: @Psylent `\item[]`

Comment: Or try \item[~]

Comment: Thanks. \item[] works.